# HTML / CSS - Cross Shape with picture in it

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I created a cross shape with css. Now I'd like to put a picture in it, the problem is that, the cross contains before: and after: div so its not possible to put a picture in it.

Here is my jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/iYogaCE/1/edit

How could I manage that? Or is there another solution to create a shape like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not setting a background image for a cross-shape here. You're just making cross-shape with 2 strips with background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background-position:center;` in `#cross:before, #cross:after`

```
#cross {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
}

#cross:before, #cross:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size:100px 100px;
  background-image:url('http://www.gm-consult.de/uploads/pics/homer-simpson_20.jpg');
  background-position:center;
}

#cross:before {
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: -15%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#cross:after {
  top: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-top: -15%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Thx that worked very well! Now I got another confusing part. I'd like that the background picture isn't rotated, when I add a rotate to the :before, : after (where I placed the picture) it won't change anything. The problem is I can't change the rotation of the other attributes (Otherwise it wont stay as a cross) -> http://jsbin.com/iYogaCE/7/edit